# How to browserify module ethereumjs-tx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, blockchain, ethereum

I have this demo code I want to broserify:

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
var privateKey = new Buffer('e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109', 'hex')

var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', 
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
  value: '0x00', 
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx)
tx.sign(privateKey)

var serializedTx = tx.serialize()
console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'))
```

I have installed ethereum-tx almost succesfully like this:

```
npm install -g ethereumjs-tx
    ...
    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json'
    npm WARN root No description
    npm WARN root No repository field.
    npm WARN root No README data
    npm WARN root No license field.
```

I am not sure whether these warning messages are important or I just should ignore them...

Nevertheless code above runs ok in nodejs. But the problem appears when trying to broserify it, creating a file main.js that is the code above and:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
    Error: Cannot find module 'ethereumjs-tx' from 'myHomeDir'
```

My nodejs has a folder for ethereumjs-tx, that seems ok to me:

```
# ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-tx/
total 84
drwxr-xr-x  6 nobody root  4096 Jan 11 08:46 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root   root  4096 Jan 11 08:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody root  4096 Dec 14 00:14 docs
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody root  4096 Dec 14 00:14 examples
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root  2028 Dec 14 00:14 fake.js
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root  7395 Dec 15 03:40 index.js
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root   600 Dec 14 00:14 karma.conf.js
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root 16726 Dec 14 00:14 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x 76 root   root  4096 Jan 11 08:46 node_modules
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root  1187 Dec 14 00:14 .npmignore
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root  3955 Dec 14 00:18 .package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root  4369 Jan 11 08:46 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root  1871 Dec 15 03:40 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody root  4096 Jan 11 08:46 test
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root   599 Dec 14 00:14 .travis.yml
```

Any hint about how to get this code broserified? What am I doing wrong? Thx!

Comment: Maybe save the module to your devDependencies with `npm i --save-dev moduleName`, than you can use `var tx = require("moduleName")`

Comment: And qan explanation for the warnings: they just telling you what is missing in your package.json file to be complete. Its no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install any module locally in order to browserify it. At least, I didn't find any option to get browserify to work with globally installed packages.

So, in the root of your project, you need to do:

```
npm install ethereumjs-tx --save-dev
```

`--save` indicates the package will not only be downloaded to a local `node_modules` folder, but also will modify your `package.json` and write down the dependency, so any further `npm install` command over that `package.json` will install `ethereumjs-tx` with the same version.

`-dev` indicates that the package will be saved as a development dependency, which means is not a package used by your application in production **as a node application**: so every package you bundle to be used in the client side should be a devDependency.

When you run `npm install`, npm expects a valid `package.json` to exist. The warnings npm is complaining about are due to a this `package.json` not existing in your project, and thus not having some `package.json` fields such as `description`. An easy way to initialize a `package.json` when you don't have one is to run `npm init`.

In fact it seems you're creating the bundle at '/root/', which seems a strage location for a web project.

Comment: the answer was allready in the comments, but really nice explanation :-)